# Llenar un Input a partir de 2 select option - PHP

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

estoy intentando llenar un input a partir de 2 select

Al llenar estos 2 select

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que me llene un input en base a esos 2 select mas un numero alphanumerico en esta nomenclatura

**01-02-FHG**

El cual el **01** es el select de zona,

el **02** es el select del sector,

el **FHG** que sea un codigo aleatorio de cualquier letra

Pero no se como hacerlo si alguien me ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debe ser algo similar:

```
$zona = $_POST['zona'];
$sector = $_POST['sector'];
$dato = $zona."-".$sector."-".time();
```

time — Devuelve la fecha Unix actual, con esto no deberias tener problemas